# How to change specific href without having ID or name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

This is all I have. Is there any way to change href?

```
 <a style="color: #0C82FD;" target="_blank" href="www.stapre.lt">www.stapre.lt</a>
```

Comment: It depends on the if the a tag is nested. Can you give a class to the parent container?

Comment: `$('a[href="www.stapre.lt"]').prop('href', '...')`

Comment: If that `href` is unique - you can query it by that

Comment: `$('a[href="www.stapre.lt"]');`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) (by the way, `href` doesn't pre-suppose a protocol, so adding `http://` is worthwhile):

```
<a style="color: #0C82FD;" target="_blank" href="http://www.stapre.lt">www.stapre.lt</a>
```

And then changing the `href` using [`prop()`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/):

```
$('a[href="http://www.stapre.lt"]').prop('href', 'http://google.com');
```

This of course assumes you don't have other `<a>` elements with the same `href` attribute value. If you do, you can then use [`index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) to filter them down.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery selector as BenM said or you can navigate by DOM using:

```
document.links[ElementIndex].href = 'mypage.com';
```